# Datagridview to multiple .txt files

Tags: vb.net

I’m using a datagridview to save multiple .txt files to a folder.  Column 1 is the filename and column 2 is the content of the file.

I’m trying to loop through the entire datagridview, but the only .txt file being produced is the one where the little arrow is in the row header.  This happens even if I have multiple rows highlighted/selected.  How do I make .txt files for all of the selected rows?  Thanks.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("D:\samplefolder\" & DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString & ".txt", DataGridView1.SelectedCells(1).Value.ToString, False)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a For Each loop is to sequentially access each item in a list.  Your loop control variable in that code is 'row' yet you never use that variable inside the loop.  You always use the same two cells inside the loop so you just keep writing the same file over and over.  Inside the loop, 'row' contains the current row so use it.  Get the two cells you want from 'row'.
By the way, it's good practice to use Path.Combine to combine partial paths.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but some sample code of your explanation would be helpful.

Comment: So would a bit of effort on your part.  You posted your comment 7 minutes after mine.  What effort did you make to follow my instructions in that 7 minutes?  The instructions are simple.  Follow them.  If you try and fail then I can help but if you won't even try then why should I?

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("D:\samplefolder\" & row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & ".txt", row.Cells(1).Value.ToString, False)
Next row
```

End Sub